# Using Ruby Gem That Uses an API - Setting Up Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails. I am trying to implement https://www.kraken.com/help/api

Incase it isn't obvious, my knowledge of implementing API's and gems is very basic.

I go to the "example-api-code" paragraph and I get to https://github.com/leishman/kraken_ruby

I include the gem and do the bundle.

Now we get to "Usage" "Create A Client"

I assume I put the following in `config/kraken.rb`

```
API_KEY = '3bH+M/nLp......'
API_SECRET = 'wQG+7Lr9b.....'

kraken = Kraken::Client.new(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

time = kraken.server_time
time.unixtime #=> 1393056191
```

I wanted to test something simple, such as displaying the time.

I put the following code in my views/welcome/index.html.erb file, but then I get an error.

```
<p><%= kraken.server_time %></p> 
-> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `kraken' for #<#<Class:0x007f95c6246ba8>:0x007f95c6245eb0>):
```

Trying this code in my html.erb file and it gives me another error

```
<p><%= @kraken.server_time %></p>
-> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `server_time' for nil:NilClass):
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

EDIT: Solutions Attempts, TLDR `NameError (uninitialized constant...`

---

@ Gladis

Using your solution I get this error

```
->! Unable to load application: SyntaxError: /app/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:5: dynamic constant assignment
->  API_KEY = '...'
```

So I tried

```
def index
  @kraken = Kraken::Client.new('3bH+M/nLp...', 'wQG+7Lr9b...')
  time = @kraken.server_time
  time.unixtime #=> 1393056191 
end
```

and got this new error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant WelcomeController::Kraken):
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

---

@ Pavel Tkackenko

Your first solution (wrapping in singleton-like class) gives me this error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::KrakenClient):
  app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_welcome_index_html_erb__3584347874708863751_70226442404480'
    1: <p><%= KrakenClient.get.server_time %></p>
```

Your second solutions (monkey-patch) gives me the this error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Kraken):
    1: <p><%= Kraken.client.server_time %></p>
  app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_welcome_index_html_erb___3719740865851336982_69820265644620'
```

---

**Moving `/config/kraken.rb` to `/config/initializers/kraken.rb` using Pavel's method**

Wrapping it in singleton-like class gives me this error (infact, it doesn't even let me host the server)

```
->When I host it on my local computer with bin/rails server
/config/initializers/kraken.rb:6:in `<class:KrakenClient>': uninitialized constant KrakenClient::Kraken (NameError)
/config/initializers/kraken.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


->When I host it on heroku
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant KrakenClient::Kraken
/config/initializers/kraken.rb:5:in `<class:KrakenClient>'
/config/initializers/kraken.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

With monkey-patch I get this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Kraken::Client):
  1: <p><%= Kraken.client.server_time %></p>
config/initializers/kraken.rb:8:in `client'
app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_welcome_index_html_erb___577296263292451462_70097201303100'
```

If you got it to work on your computer, I would be happy to use your code as a skeleton (I am assuming this will be easier than figuring out what's wrong on my side).

Comment: You must create a variable **@kraken**, and set its value, inside the controller/method invoking this view. Then **@kraken** will be available when the view is rendered.

Comment: I think than custom files in `/config` are not loaded into your environment. Please move `kraken.rb` to `config/initializers` folder and restart server.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in WelcomeController.rb

```
  def index
    API_KEY = '3bH+M/nLp......'
    API_SECRET = 'wQG+7Lr9b.....'
    @kraken = Kraken::Client.new(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    time = @kraken.server_time
    time.unixtime #=> 1393056191 
  end
```

In view under this controller put:

```
<p><%= @kraken.server_time %></p>
```

Comment: @kraken will not be accessible in models and other controllers.

Comment: Oviously, it depends from what he want to do with this variable. If he wants only share something in view, it enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
kraken = Kraken::Client.new(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
```

`kraken` here is local variable. If you put it into config/kraken.rb, it will not be accessible outside.

There are different solutions. One is to wrap it in singleton-like class:

```
# config/initializers/kraken.rb

class KrakenClient

  API_KEY = '3bH+M/nLp......'
  API_SECRET = 'wQG+7Lr9b.....'

  @@config = Kraken::Client.new(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

  def self.get
    @@config
  end
end

# index.html.erb

<p><%= KrakenClient.get.server_time %></p>
```

Another one approach is to monkey-patch `Kraken` itself:

```
# config/initializers/kraken.rb
class Kraken

  API_KEY = '3bH+M/nLp......'
  API_SECRET = 'wQG+7Lr9b.....'

  class << self
    def client
      @client ||=  Kraken::Client.new(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    end
  end
end

# index.html.erb

<p><%= Kraken.client.server_time %></p>
```